# How to implement facebook verification on new Metadata of Next.js 13?

Tags: facebook, next.js, metadata

My old nextjs website had a meta with name and content in the _document file inside a head, like:

```
<Html>
 <head>
  <meta name='facebook-domain-verification' content:'00000000000000' />
  *more stuff...*
 </head>
</html>
```

I read the Next.js generateMetadata documentation and I saw a lot of pre-built meta. But I don't get how I can implement a new meta. Making a experience, I created something like the robots meta they use there:

```
export const metadata = {

robots: {
    index: true,
    follow: true,
    nocache: true,
    googleBot: {
      index: true,
      follow: true,
      noimageindex: true,
      'max-video-preview': -1,
      'max-image-preview': 'large',
      'max-snippet': -1,
    },
 },

*a lot of stuff ...* 

other:{
name: 'facebook-domain-verification',
content: '00000000000000000', 
},
```

I saw some contents saying to use "other" to place third's metadata, but I'm a little confuse.

Can you help me?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For verification NextJS implements the `verification` key inside metadata object like so:

```js
export const metadata = {
  verification: {
    google: 'google',
    yandex: 'yandex',
    yahoo: 'yahoo',
    other: {
      me: ['my-email', 'my-link'],
    },
  },
}
```

You can read more about metadata verification at [nextjs docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#verification)

Answer (score 0):

you can add meta tags directly in your /app/layout.tsx

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta name='facebook-domain-verification' content:'00000000000000' />
  </head>
  <body>
    {children}
  </body>
</html>
```